# How to use watchdog to know when a file was downloaded?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I have a funtion that downloads files with a given link. If the file takes too much time to be downloaded, the script report error. Then I added `time.sleep(30)`
but is to much time to wait for small files that can be downloaded in 1 second. Like this:

```
for link in links:
    download_function(link)
    time.sleep(30) ### I added this sleep but is to much to wait for small files.

    rest of the code
    .
    .
```

Then I want to add a watchdog process to know when the file was actually downloaded and then continue with rest of code.

I tested the following code that works correctly by itself, checking when the directory is modified and reports when file was downloaded.

```
import sys
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

## Watcher code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    watchDirectory = '/Path/To/Directory/'

    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, watchDirectory, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.isAlive():
            observer.join(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()


<ObservedWatch: path=/Path/To/Directory/, is_recursive=True>
2020-06-01 14:42:05 - Created file: /Path/To/Directory/somefile.pdf
2020-06-01 14:42:06 - Modified directory: /Path/To/Directory/
```

But I don't know to use the watchdog code (instead of time.sleep(30)) as a function in order to wait until the file is downloaded to be able to continue with the rest of code.

something like this:

```
def download_complete(DirToWatch):
    Watcher code here
    .
    .

    download_complete = false

    If download_complete==true:
        stop watcher

    return true


for link in links:
    download_function(link)

    if download_complete(DirToWatch) == true:
        continue with rest of the code

    rest of the code
    .
    .
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not an especially good way to handle this. Watchdog isn’t very portable and has some oddball behaviors.

The most direct way would be to use an asynchronous download with a callback / handler function that runs after the download. Here’s a good example:

https://gist.github.com/Hammer2900/2b5da5c08f6406ab49ddb02b0c5ae9f7

Another approach that doesn’t reside completely within one Python program would be to use durable message queues, e.g. one function adds a message to queue 1 to request a download; another function monitors queue 1, performs the download, and adds a message to queue 2 to request file handling; another function monitors queue 2 and does the post-processing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'n new to python and My `download_function()` basically contains the command `driver.get(link)` to download a file, since is part of a `Selenium Chromedriver` code. how can be done a "mix" between my download function and your suggested code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to monitor whenever a file have been downloaded in the current folder:

```
from sys import argv
from time import sleep
from logging import basicConfig, INFO
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    basicConfig(level=INFO)
    path = argv[1] if len(argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    obs = Observer()
    obs.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    obs.start()
    obs.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how to insert the code you propose within my code?